# Android Studio2.3.3 writing to file

Tags: android

I have created a file and written into the file using editText. Now I want to write into a file named "note.txt". But the content to be written should be stored in a variable. Can any one help me with the code??

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void writeFile() {

   File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   // ==> /storage/emulated/0/note.txt
   String path = extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName;
   Log.i("ExternalStorageDemo", "Save to: " + path);

   String data = editText.getText().toString();

   try {
       File myFile = new File(path);
       myFile.createNewFile();
       FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
       OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
       myOutWriter.append(data);
       myOutWriter.close();
       fOut.close();

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fileName + " saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?:

```
private void save(String inputText) {
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try{
        out = openFileOutput("note.txt",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
        writer.write(inputText);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try{
            if (writer!=null);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah. This is code. But I need variable containing my text.

Comment: In this code the text is written in file  after creating application and I give the text in the application. But I need variable containing my text (I mean input text eg str="apple hi hello.")in the code itself.